# How to load data from Excel file stored in SharePoint to MS Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, sharepoint

I've been trying to load an excel file stored on SharePoint to my access database, but I get this message that only XML files can be loaded from Internet. So is there a solution to this situation like an Access Add-in or something.

What I exactly need is to create a link between the excel file and the database so when the file gets updated, I get the new records on my database.

By the way I'm not a programmer, I'm an HR Specialist trying to manage HR data.

Comment: Have you tried to open the Excel file and copy/paste the data into Access?

Comment: I'm HR Specialist not a dumb.
Anyway, what I want to do is to create a link between the excel file and the database so that when the file gets updated I get the new records in my database.

Comment: Most likely you can only create such a link with a local Excel file, not one that resides on a SP server.

Comment: Isn't there some tool like power query for excel or some simlpe ETL that I can use for this purpose? Cause the files I am trying to load are used frequently by many people on SharePoint so I can't really store them at local. And thank you anyway.

Comment: How about if you map a SharePoint document library to a network drive on your computer? http://mroffice365.com/2012/02/using-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work ! Same error !

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: ... only XML files can be loaded from Internet ...

Comment: First, map a network drive to a SP document library. Then, from Access, create a link to the data in Excel. See https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-Excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958 , the last part of the article describes linking to Excel data.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this but there is actually a stackexchange for [sharepoint here][1].  It's possible that someone there might have answers that people here don't.


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you know this but there is actually a stackexchange for [sharepoint here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).  It's possible that someone there might have answers that people here don't.